# Input shape of torch vector (translation from keras code)

Tags: python, tensorflow, torch

I am trying to build a neural network with pytorch. Most of it came from a code that was written using tensorflow. I am translating my code from tensorflow to use it in pytorch. But something is not right. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
    self.initializer = nn.init.normal_

    ops = nn.Parameter(torch.empty(h_size, h_size, num_points * 2))
    inputs = torch.empty((0, 1296), requires_grad=True)

    self.x = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(num_points, 16 * 16 * 2, bias=False),
        nn.LeakyReLU(),
        #nn.Reshape((16, 16, 2)),
    )

    self.conv_transpose_1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(2, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
        nn.InstanceNorm2d(64),
        nn.LeakyReLU(),
    )

    self.conv_transpose_2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False),
        nn.InstanceNorm2d(64),
        nn.LeakyReLU(),
    )

    self.conv_transpose_3 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False),
    )

    self.conv_transpose_4 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 2, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False),
    )

def forward(self, ops, inputs):
    x = self.x(inputs)
    x = self.conv_transpose_1(x)
    x = self.conv_transpose_2(x)
    x = self.conv_transpose_3(x)
    x = self.conv_transpose_4(x)
    x = self.density_matrix(x)
    complex_ops = convert_to_complex_ops(ops)
    x = self.expectation(complex_ops, x, prefactor)

    return x
```

In tensorflow, the ops and inputs was:

```
ops = tf.keras.layers.Input(
    shape=[h_size, h_size, num_points * 2], name="ops"
)
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_points), name="inputs")
```

The `ops` and `inputs` is to instantiate inputs for a conditional GAN.

In Torch, the forarwd function is:

```
def forward(self, ops, inputs):
    x = self.x(inputs)
    x = self.conv_transpose_1(x)
    x = self.conv_transpose_2(x)
    x = self.conv_transpose_3(x)
    x = self.conv_transpose_4(x)
    x = self.density_matrix(x)
    complex_ops = convert_to_complex_ops(ops)
    prefactor = 1.0
    x = self.expectation(complex_ops, x, prefactor)
    x = self.noise(x)
```

But I got the following error when running `x=conv_transpose_1(x)`:

```
RuntimeError: Expected 3D (unbatched) or 4D (batched) input to conv_transpose2d,
but got input of size: [0, 512]
```

In Tensorflow, `ops` and `Inputs` have shape:

```
In [63]: ops.shape
Out[63]: TensorShape([None, 16, 16, 2592])

In [64]: inputs.shape
Out[64]: TensorShape([None, 1296])
```

But the 'translation' to Pytorch is giving erros, and I believe it is on how I am defining the ops and inputs in the first place. I know that Torch's `nn.Conv2d` expects an input in the shape `[batch_size, channels, height, width]` but I am not getting on how to make it right. This is an exercise I gave to myself to understand Pytorch, but I am stucked on it.

Any help???

Edit: the original tensorflow code, which work just fine is:

```
initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0.0, 0.02)

ops = tf.keras.layers.Input(
    shape=[h_size, h_size, num_points * 2], name="opS"
)
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_points), name="inputs")

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    16 * 16 * 2,
    use_bias=False,
    kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(0.0, 0.02),
)(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((16, 16, 2))(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    64, 4, use_bias=False, strides=1, padding="same", kernel_initializer=initializer
)(x)
x = tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization(axis=3)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    64, 4, use_bias=False, strides=1, padding="same", kernel_initializer=initializer
)(x)
x = tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization(axis=3)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    32, 4, use_bias=False, strides=1, padding="same", kernel_initializer=initializer
)(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    2, 4, use_bias=False, strides=1, padding="same", kernel_initializer=initializer
)(x)
complex_ops = convert_to_complex_ops(ops)
prefactor = 1.0
x = Expectation()(complex_ops, x, prefactor)
x = tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(noise)(x)

return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[ops, inputs], outputs=x)
```

Comment: I believe you should try to build easier models in pytorch first, so you can understand how it works, and not going to gans directly.

Comment: I'm not sure what your first sequential layer `x` is trying to do? you pass in a vector of shape 1296 through a linear layer  which outputs a vector of 512 size, then magically you want to convolve on a vector? your conv_transpose_1 should have channel in to be 1, and kernel size to be 64 and output channel to be 1

Comment: The reshape in the Sequential should be nn.Reshape((2, 16, 16)) i guess. Maybe that was the problem.

Comment: @TheEngineerProgrammer The nn.Reshape is commented because it actually does not exist in Torch. It came from the tensorflow code and I naively just rewrite it just to discover that in torch it does not exist

Comment: @darthbaba I want to pass the vector of shape 1296 as an input vector to the first layer. I edited the question with the original tensorflow code, which should make it clear.

Comment: oh, yeah, but you still need to reshape it, so you need to do it in forward.